# How to parse this string to json or array format in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

This is a return from Google Adwords API

```
Details: [fieldPath: id; trigger: Invalid predicate name: id; errorString: SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME]
```

I would like to parse it to json/array like this:

```
"Details": {
 "fieldPath": "id", 
 "trigger": "Invalid predicate", 
 "name": "id", 
 "errorString": "SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you fail? Can we see code?

Comment: Did you trying to use `json_encode()` function?

Comment: `json_encode` won't work, this isn't an array.

Comment: You could do it like: https://3v4l.org/Osu2l - or use regex, but the problem is there is no separator before name.

Comment: @J.Litvak  I already tried `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` doesn't work

Comment: @kerbholz I already tried `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` doesn't work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thats amazing what you did. Let me try it out.

Comment: I can't guarantee it would work for all errors returned, thats why im not confident to post it as an answer.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Works perfectly! you should answer it down so that Ill mark it as answered.

Comment: @Kenn answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the string into a parsable format with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Then [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) into an array. It's not guaranteed to work for all strings returned, but answers your question.

```
<?php
$str = 'Details: [fieldPath: id; trigger: Invalid predicate name: id; errorString: SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME]';

// strip out details and []
$str = str_replace(['[',']', 'Details:'], '', $str);

// fix name and replace seperators
$str = str_replace([': ', ';', ' name='], ['=', '&', '&name='], $str);

// parse string into $array variable
parse_str($str, $array);

$json = ['Details' => $array];

print_r(json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

https://3v4l.org/nKa6b

**Result:**

```
{
    "Details": {
        "fieldPath": "id",
        "trigger": "Invalid predicate",
        "name": "id",
        "errorString": "SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME"
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is exactly what I want! works perfectly! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to create a parser for those message formats. This is bit hacky solution, but you could convert that format to json format and then json_decode it. the general idea:

1. find anything in the square brackets including them (regex: **([[].*[]])$**)
2. replace ";" with ","
3. add quotes to the string values
4. json_decode(result)

But i would start by investigating their (google's) api, they might have an option to retrieve the data as json